# Why is $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt5]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

1. Why is $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt5]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5)$ ?

$\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt5]$={$a+ib\sqrt5,a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$}

2. Also can $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt5]$ be seen as a ring of polynomial in $"i\sqrt5"$ or is it just a notation looking like the polynomial ring notation but with another meaning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

$$\phi: \Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z[\sqrt5\,i]\;,\;\;\;\phi(f(x)):=f(\sqrt5\,i)$$

It is not hard to show this is a ring homomorphism, and

$$\ker\phi=\{f\in\Bbb Z[x]\;|\;f(\sqrt5\,i)=0\;$$

All you need now is to prove that $\;f(\sqrt5\,i)=0\iff (x^2+5)\,\mid f(x)\;$ , which means $\;f(\sqrt5\,i)=0\iff f(x)=(x^2+5)g(x)\;$ , for some $\;g(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\;$ .

The above also explains why in $\;\Bbb Z[\sqrt5\,i]=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\;$ we get an expression with only **linear polynomials** in $\;\sqrt{-5}\;$ ....

Answer (score 0):

The ring $R=\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+5\rangle$ contains a zero of $x^2+5$, namely the residue class $x+\langle x^2+5\rangle$, which we denote by $x$ itself.

For this residue class, $x^2+5=0$ and so $x = \pm i\sqrt 5$. Thus both zeros lie in $R$. The elements of this ring have the form $a+bx$, with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$. This ring is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z[i\sqrt 5]$ whose elements are $a+bi\sqrt 5$, with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$.